# Retrieve information about an open file

Tags: c++, c, stdio, cstdio

Can I retrieve information about a file previously opened with `fopen()` using only the pointer it returned?

The reason I ask is that I am trying to write a RAII-style wrapper class for `FILE *`s, and I want to make it as general as possible, and one of the functions I imagined for it was a copy-like operation, that would take a `FILE *` as an argument, and create a new reference to the same file.

Under POSIX, I can create a duplicate of a file descriptor with `dup()`/`dup2()`, and even get how the file is being accessed with `fnctl()`'s `F_GETFL` operation.  However, even if I do that to the underlying descriptor of a `FILE *`, it isn't enough for guessing properties such as if the stream is text or binary (under POSIX, there no real difference, but I want to be general), or its orientation towards `char`- or `wchar_t`-based text.

So, is there is a way of learning about the stream I'm about to create a wrapper for, how far can I go, and how should I do it?

Thank you for you attention.

Comment: What kind of information? Data contained within a file? What do you mean by information about a file?

Comment: [man fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: Is it perhaps an option to make a non-copyable internal type and handle that thing with a `shared_ptr`? Or perhaps bake your own refcounting? It would avoid the necessity to use the operating system's refcounting.

Comment: @Asadefa, not the data in a file, but aspects about it, such as the mode it was opened with, if `fwide()` was applied to it, what kind of buffering it is using, and things like that.  Note that these are all open-time or close-to-open-time information, since neither `setvbuf()` nor `fwide()` are supposed to be called at any other time than just right after `fopen()`, and before any reading or writing takes place.

Comment: Why would you want to have two `FILE*` streams for one open file description?  What with the buffering (in general), that seems more trouble than useful.  Why wouldn’t you just want to reuse the `FILE*` if you’re going to share the description anyway?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I don't.  What I wanted to do was to get information about the file modes of operation to possibly replicate them (with occasional variations) in a second `FILE *` with a different file underlying descriptor altogether, so different parts of the program (different sub-programs, really) could work on the same file in an independent but consistent way.

Comment: @Paulo1205: That’s not what `dup`/`dup2` do, though.